# Get Percentage of Width

Tags: c#

I have been looking through answers on here and i know this is similar to other questions but what i have tried gives me the incorrect result. I am drawing a graph in c#. I have a width as seen below.

```
public const int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1920;    //canvas heigh
public const int IMAGE_WIDTH = 1080;     //canvas width
public const int BOREHOLE_RECT_WIDTH = (IMAGE_WIDTH / 2 - (10 * MARGIN));
```

The important value is BOREHOLE_RECT_WIDTH which returns as 240. I am trying to work out what 15 percent is of this value. I have checked this on the website below and others and 15 percent of 240 is 36.

[Percentage Calculator](http://www.percentagecalculator.net/)

However when i use the code below i get a result of 6 which does not seem correct to me.

```
 int percent = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * 15) / (double)BOREHOLE_RECT_WIDTH);
```

I am not sure what im doing wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: var fifteenPercent = someValue * 0.15. JUST THIS

Comment: or to avoid possible rounding problems (and maybe get overflow errors): `someValue * 15 / 100;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te get 15 percent of somethin You just need to multiply it by 0.15. For instance

```
var percent = Value * 0.15; // if Value == 240 thant percent will be 36
```

Or You can write a method for it so You will be able to get any percentage You want for example:

```
public double PercentOf(double percent, double number)
{
    return number * (percent / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating what 1500 / 240 is currently, which equals to 6.25.
If you want to get the answer you either have to do:

```
(240 ÷ 100) × 15
```

OR

```
240 * 0.15
```